# How To download web page using java as well preserve image files

Tags: java

How to download the page and the images given the url using java. A similar question was avaialble already, which when tried just saves the page and not the images.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to download the page (HTML), then parse the HTML, find the <img> tags in there, and download the images (the src attribute of the <img> tag is the URL of the image file). Likewise you might want to download accompanying CSS or JavaScript files for the page.

Comment: regex can match all those tags for you.
god forbid its one of those new fangled pages that use javascript for everything.

Answer (score 1):

[Java makes it easy to copy files from a Web site](http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip19.html)